# Where can I get a opinon / review about my music? I'm self-taught, so music college is not an option

Tags: composition, self-learning, beginner

When I got enough time I learn and try to compose at least a simple piece of music but I don't know a place where it's sure that I would get criticism and opinion about it and if I make something good than it won't be copied.

I tried to create some dungeon synth and synth song weeks ago.

I frist tried soundcloud with the synth songs...well...I didn't have much practice back than but still because I don't have big and successfull statistics I can't even find myself on the page which is pretty ironic.

I tried bandcamp with my dungeon synth music as a "totally free album". I even send the link to one of the D.Synth youtube channels but my I'm not professional so I'm exactly where I'm with soundcloud.

Now the more classical like ones I don't have much idea. I'm pretty beginner so I don't wanna make it complicated with own web sites and all sort of things.

About the classical part...I've been composing more "orchestral-like" music recently. I cannot say it's pure classical because I still have much to learn about music theory so there's at least as much intuition and improvisation as much theory (if not more) but still it's not professional so I don't wanna go to paid web pages or anything like that.

Also I'm afraid I'm a little paranoid about "What if my song got copied?" thing. I understand that I have to create something good enough but I don't know if there is a way to make it a little bit more safe.

Comment: please add something about the style of your music, that could matter when looking for an audience.

Comment: You could ask for opinions on Gearslutz or the SOS forum. Both have 'post your music' sections. Better gird your loins though, not everyone is encouraging and polite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting online to random unqualified sources will earn you random, unqualified feedback. Yes, college might not be an option for you, but there’s nothing wrong with reaching out to the graduate students of a college and asking for lessons.

I suggest emailing a professor at a local college and ask if there are any graduate composition students interested in giving private lessons. You might get a bite. Remember that when you ask for feedback, you’re asking to make your music better not be petted like a cat. Don’t ask family members or friends.

Last, and this is a cold truth: no one will steal your music because no one cares enough about you or your music to steal it. I have no use for some beginner’s music. That said, don’t post your tracks Willy-nilly online because robots can and do steal recordings and post them on other sites. Control your content as much as you can. Tough words but hopefully they release you from feeling paranoid. Focus on your passion, not your fear.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've actually had one of my original compositions stolen and used without credit. Because I publish on Musescore, which reveals sheet music by default, I've figured that copying is inevitable, so I publish all my compositions with the Creative Commons Attribution license. ...Which means that all I did (and really felt like I could do) was make the user provide the proper credit. ...I'm actually more sore about the transcription of another Musescore user's work that I released with his/her permission that got stolen in a similar fashion, complete with crediting neither of us.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot to 'unpack' in your question: beginner, self-taught, opinion, review, criticism, copyright.

I'll skip the copyright part. That's law. Read up on that and handle your music accordingly.

Some personal observations:

Music professors will offer technical advise on the *craft* of writing. From an emotional perspective they will encourage you to keep writing. You are more likely to hear something like 'you did this here, but you could also have done option 2 or option 3.' You probably won't hear 'you did this here and it moved me deeply.'

Students will offer all kinds of emotional reactions. But, it typically goes two ways: the praise for you that they really want to hear about themselves, or the harsh payback critique from someone you have criticized.

Friends and family will usually say something like: 'that's nice.' Occasionally, you might get 'I could never write music.'

All the above are generalizations, but based on real experiences.

*Once* my wife *voluntarily* said she like a 'Gay 90's' style waltz I wrote.

The only real emotional comment I ever heard was from a co-worker/friend who listened to an 8 bar, minor key, *exercise* I wrote. He said: 'damn, why you gotta be making me cry!' From the perspective of craft I have no idea why I got that reaction. It was an electronic playback with strings and oboe, slow tempo, and some non-chord tones.

Those were nice compliments, but in terms of development it didn't help me much.

So, having shared all that I think you should ask yourself this: as a beginner what exactly do you want? Do you want the kind of feedback a professional would give? Do you want emotional feedback with no insight to the craft or worst is not genuine?

Of course that question is rhetorical. My advice is to get the advice of professionals or at least those with a serious approach to learning the craft.

Try to distinguish between: opinion, criticism, review, etc. Mere opinion is not objective, an audience of one. Formal criticism should be de-personalized and based on some objective understanding, the realm of the professionals. A review is written to inform the public, it could be good or bad, but 'there's no such thing as bad publicity.' Online followers, likes, etc. I would put in the review category, because in the end those are about publicity.

Wanting feedback from lots of people is a natural desire, but I really think it is more important to develop a good sense of *self criticism*. Good teachers should advise you at a level appropriate for your level. The more you push yourself, the deeper the advice you can then receive. Seek out *quality* relationships not the greatest number of commentators.

Two final anecdotes.

After college I kept studying. Eventually I mailed a collection of short pieces to that composition professor form college. I think I attached a short letter, but I can't remember exactly. I didn't know if I would get a reply. To my surprise he telephoned me and then wrote back a short letter. He gave me a few tips and words of encouragement.

More recently I send some 'cold' emails to two professors who wrote theory books I really like. I explained how I was trying to apply ideas presented in the books to my studies. In one case I attached a score for a sonata exposition. I received replies from both professors including a copy of my score with revisions from the professor.

I took me a long time to build up the nerve to approach those professors as I was not one of their students. I made sure to be brief and specific and appreciative. No vague questions. No nagging follow up emails.

You could try reaching out to people this way, but make sure you start with critiquing yourself.

Comment: My family actually generally aren't supportive of my compositions. My mom thinks it's a waste of time. My brother (and actually some other listeners) thinks I'm too chord-heavy. (Granted, he prefers the arpeggio-heavy Touhou music more.) My cousin is supportive, though, but we've been estranged for years.